# How to fill cells in tkinter table automatically Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried to incorporate this piece into my script and add the calculation into column 7, however, it appears to be failing to return correct multiple of inputs, any idea why? Here is the code:

```
def autofill(self, event):
    row = int(event.widget.grid_info()['row'])
    auto_list = self.in_list(self.LookUpList, self._entry[row, 0].get())

    if auto_list is not None:

        self._entry[row,1].delete(0, 'end')
        self._entry[row,1].insert(0, auto_list[1])

        self._entry[row,2].delete(0, 'end')
        self._entry[row,2].insert(0, auto_list[2])

        self._entry[row,4].delete(0, 'end')
        self._entry[row,4].insert(0, auto_list[3])

        self._entry[row,6].delete(0,'end')
        if self._entry[row,3].get() != '':
            a = self._entry[row,3].get()
        else: a = 0
        b = int(self._entry[row,4].get())
        c = int(a * b)
        self._entry[row,6].insert(0, c)
```

I have just found the error, had to convert one variable into int, then it worked:

```
        self._entry[row,6].delete(0,'end')
        if self._entry[row,3].get() != '':
            a = int(self._entry[row,3].get())
        else: a = 0
        b = int(self._entry[row,4].get())
        c = int(a * b)
        self._entry[row,6].insert(0, c)
```

Comment: So my understanding of this is that you want it so that if anything from one of the sublists is filled out in a position, the rest of the line is filled out with the other values in the sublist. Do these ***need*** to be an `Entry` widget, this would be far, far easier with an `Optionmenu` widget.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction, I would like it to be entry widget to prevent reconstruction of my whole code. Do you have any suggestion how to proceed? Thanks

Comment: It's incredibly complicated, I started working on a solution for this an hour or so ago but stopped frankly because it wasn't interesting and using `Entry` widget's that allow free text entry when you're going to be restricting what the user is allowed to enter anyway is backwards and inefficient. Yes this is possible, but you're going to have to put in more effort to push forwards than to go back and rewrite it (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_cost)

Comment: This question is too vague. What part of the problem do you need help with? Do you know how to create entry widgets? Do you know how to insert data into an entry widget? Do you know how to look search a  list? Do you know how to do bindings? What part of that do you need help with?

Comment: with all respect, I do not think that the question is too vague. Perhaps, I should be more concrete when posting it but basically what I need is: populate values returned from function into appropriate cell as stated within original question. Hopefully, it is clearer now. Thanks

Comment: I will appreciate any suggestion that will be concrete. The advantage of this approach I saw is that it will automatically fill some information based upon user input but if needed and the user still will be able to overwrite it (which I am not quite sure whether it is possible within Optionmenu).

Comment: Why do you need the user to overwrite it if you're going to be filling out the cells based on predefined information? I think this is a classic XY problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: It's still not clear what "stuck" means. Do you need help with inserting text into a widget? To look up the data in a list? To react to a keypress? I recommend you rewrite the code in the question so that you're only trying to update a single entry. Once you learn how to do a single entry, a row of entries should be simple. See [mcve]

Comment: @Ethan if the app automatically populates the cells I still want the users to have possibility to write their own text if desired. I am clearly new to this and cannot understand how this works. I posted a question here because I needed help but as I can see none of you are interested in giving a hand rather than writing never ending questions

Comment: @Bryan, I have tested all parts of that code within the first section, it worked, problem occurred whenI tried to write into the cell of table by = in_list(LookUpList,self._entry[row,1])[1].

Comment: So what you're saying is simply that you don't know how to insert a string into an entry widget? Am I understanding that right? Why do you need 125 lines of code to illustrate that?

Comment: I added the whole code that creates the table after the first reaction because I wanted to provide more detail on where is the problem and where I got stuck. I thought I expressed my self clearly, perhaps not. This is a good example of your never ending questions rather then providing an answer.

Comment: I haven't yet provided an answer because your question isn't clear. I think the actual question you're asking is "how do I insert text into an entry widget", but there's so much code I can't quite tell if it's that, or if it's "my code is broken, please fix it". It would have helped if you had started out by explaining that you copied most of this code and don't understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fix that does what you're asking for. The main thing to note is that, I added an `autofill` method, and a binding to the `Return` key that calls the `autofill` method. You need to hit the Return/Enter key after typing for the cells to be populated, you can change this to any other event that you prefer.

There are few other changes just to make the code work in its current state. I did not make any change regarding how efficient/elegant your implementation is, I leave that to you.

```
from tkinter import *

class SimpleTableInput(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, rows, columns):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self._entry = {}
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns

        # register a command to use for validation
        vcmd = (self.register(self._validate), "%P")

        # create the table of widgets
        for row in range(self.rows):
            for column in range(self.columns):
                index = (row, column)
                if column == 3:
                    e = Entry(self, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd)
                else:
                    e = Entry(self)
                e.grid(row=row, column=column, stick="nsew")
                self._entry[index] = e

        # adjust column weights so they all expand equally
        for column in range(self.columns):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)



##      Lookup table:
        self.LookUpList=[
                ['a','Black skirt','PP','2000'],
                ['b','Pink T-shirt','PP','1000'],
                ['c','Yellow skirt','Marela','1500'],
                ['d','White trousers','PP','2000']]

        ## Bind the Return/Enter key to populate the entries
        for row in range(self.rows):
            self._entry[row, 0].bind("<Return>", self.autofill)

    def in_list(self, list_of_lists, item):
        if not list_of_lists:
            return None
        if item in list_of_lists[0]:
            return list_of_lists[0]
        return self.in_list(list_of_lists[1:], item)



    ## The method that will be called to populate the entries
    def autofill(self, event):
        row = int(event.widget.grid_info()['row'])
        auto_list = self.in_list(self.LookUpList, self._entry[row, 0].get())
        self._entry[row,1].delete(0, 'end')
        self._entry[row,1].insert(0, auto_list[1])


    def get(self):
        '''Return a list of lists, containing the data in the table'''
        result = []
        for row in range(self.rows):
            current_row = []
            for column in range(self.columns):
                index = (row, column)
                current_row.append(self._entry[index].get())
            result.append(current_row)
        return result

    def _validate(self, P):

        if P.strip() == "":
            return True

        try:
            f = float(P)
        except ValueError:
            self.bell()
            return False
        return True

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        names = ["Cislo produktu",
                 "Popis produktu",
                 "Znacka",
                 "Mnozstvi",
                 "Jednotkova cena",
                 "Prodejna",
                 "Celkova cena"]
        frame = Frame(self)
        frame.pack(side="top", fill="both")
        for i, title in enumerate(names):
            l = Label(frame, text=title)
            l.grid(row=0, column=i)
            frame.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
        self.EmptySpace = Label(self)
        self.table = SimpleTableInput(self, 30, 7)
        self.table.pack(side="top", fill="both")
        self.EmptySpace.pack(side="top",fill="both")

##        frame1 = Frame(self)
##        frame1.pack(side="left",fill="both")
##        self.SubButton = Button(self, text="Ulozit a zavrit", command=self.on_ulozit)
##        self.StornoButton = Button(self, text="Stornovat nakup", command=self.on_storno)
##        self.SubButton.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
##        self.StornoButton.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

    def on_ulozit(self):

        data = self.table.get()
        data1 = [list(filter(None, lst)) for lst in data]
        data2 = list(filter(None, data1))
        for item in data2:
            item.append(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
##            look up property
        with open('C:\\Users\\chroustovskyj\\Desktop\\Dev_py\\App\\Data_Storage\\Data_Storage.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            writer.writerows(data2)
        root.destroy()

    def on_storno(self):
        print("This is storno.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.wm_title("Formular")
    w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=False)      
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Great, thanks for your help, it is what I was looking for!